# How can I check when Facebook changed their API?

Tags: facebook

I have an Android app that posts to a Facebook user’s wall. It allows the user to add people tags to his post. But I now read that when you tag people, Facebook requires to tag a place as well (not GPS location, but Facebook place ID).

My question is: how can I know when Facebook added this restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to check their [roadmap of completed changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap)

> **February 6, 2013**
>
> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the
>   Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id]
>   is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
>   want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
>   feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
>   action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
>   friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.

In the above, it's not explicitly stated but tagging of friends were also disabled around the same time.

You can also know when the API has changed in anyway by subscribing to the API Push Feed https://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php. There are several people out there who have this already implemented for digestion for example

- on Twitter https://twitter.com/FacebookPush
- or Facebook https://www.facebook.com/phwdbot

Comment: but this is not the restriction I was talking about. no?

Comment: btw, how did you google the above paragraph?

Comment: @EladBenda pretty sure this is the restriction. Tagging friends is related to posting to friends' walls. Both were disabled around the same time. Checkins with friends at place ids are something different.

Comment: how did you google the above paragraph?

Comment: @EladBenda https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap